# How to share content of an activity to other user?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, share

My question is: Is it possible to share content from activity to other users and if they don't have that app installed it redirects the user to download that specific app?

Comment: where you want to share content, outside your app?

Comment: Yes, for example in my activity there is info about a car. I would like to share that info with another user and if that user has my app that content will be opened in my app if not he will be redirected to google play to install that app. I hope you understand.

I know that it is easy if that content is connected to a web site but in my case, I am displaying all info in the app.

Comment: You can use Branch sdk for that. If you need code help to implement branch sdk, let me know.